# Ebay api BulkDataExchangeRequests & ReviseInventoryStatus : Missing Required Container

Tags: ebay-api

I have some issues with BulkDataExchangeRequest/ReviseInventoryStatus(using the Large Merchant Sevices api) when trying to modify the quantities of listed products. I managed to successfully make all the prerequisite requests in order to upload and process the BulkDataExchange xml (createUploadJob, uploadFileRequest, startUploadJob) but the quantities of the products did not modified on the ebay shop. I've found out that in order to get the errors of the xml itself ,not the upload jobs, I must use the DownloadFileRequest, but I am failing to fix the errors returned by it. For the 3 products that I've tried to modify the quantity with ReviseInventoryStatus I am getting a 'Missing required container' with the error code 21916253. I've checked the xml that I send but I can't figure out what exactly what it is missing. Here is the xml, any tips would be appreciated:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <BulkDataExchangeRequests>
     <Header>
         <SiteID>77</SiteID>
         <Version>955</Version>
     </Header>
     <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <errorlanguage>en_US</errorlanguage>
         <warninglevel>High</warninglevel>
         <version>955</version>
         <inventorystatus>
             <itemid>281077289788</itemid>
             <quantity>500</quantity>
             <sku>MGA10003</sku>
             <startprice>6.90</startprice>
         </inventorystatus>
     </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>   
     <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <errorlanguage>en_US</errorlanguage>
         <warninglevel>High</warninglevel>
         <version>955</version>
         <inventorystatus>
             <itemid>271171602595</itemid>
             <quantity>500</quantity>
             <sku>MGA10215</sku>
             <startprice>20.90</startprice>
         </inventorystatus>
     </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
     <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <errorlanguage>en_US</errorlanguage>
         <warninglevel>High</warninglevel>
         <version>955</version>
         <inventorystatus>
             <itemid>281449929626</itemid>
             <quantity>8</quantity>
             <sku>MGA12496.3</sku>
             <startprice>18.90</startprice>
         </inventorystatus>
     </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
 </BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

Here is the response from DownloadFileRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <BulkDataExchangeResponses xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
 <ReviseInventoryStatusResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2016-04-15T07:39:41.431Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
     <ShortMessage>Erforderlicher Container fehlt.</ShortMessage>
     <LongMessage>Erforderlicher Container fehlt.</LongMessage>
     <ErrorCode>21916253</ErrorCode>
     <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
     <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>961</Version>
    <Build>E961_UNI_API5_17901460_R1</Build>
   </ReviseInventoryStatusResponse>
 <ReviseInventoryStatusResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2016-04-15T07:39:41.565Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
     <ShortMessage>Erforderlicher Container fehlt.</ShortMessage>
     <LongMessage>Erforderlicher Container fehlt.</LongMessage>
     <ErrorCode>21916253</ErrorCode>
     <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
     <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>961</Version>
    <Build>E961_UNI_API5_17901460_R1</Build>
   </ReviseInventoryStatusResponse>
 <ReviseInventoryStatusResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2016-04-15T07:39:41.660Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
     <ShortMessage>Erforderlicher Container fehlt.</ShortMessage>
     <LongMessage>Erforderlicher Container fehlt.</LongMessage>
     <ErrorCode>21916253</ErrorCode>
     <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
     <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>961</Version>
    <Build>E961_UNI_API5_17901460_R1</Build>
   </ReviseInventoryStatusResponse>
 </BulkDataExchangeResponses>
```

Answer (score 0):

Field names are case sensitive. I've spotted a few fields in your request that are all in lowercase. For example, `<inventorystatus`> should be `<InventoryStatus>`, and `<itemid>` needs to be `<ItemID>`.

Comment: I've modified all of the field names and created a new job, but unfortunately I get the same exact response.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe it could help someone else.

Maybe you have to remove ErrorLanguage, WarningLevel and Version and leave your XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <BulkDataExchangeRequests>
     <Header>
         <SiteID>77</SiteID>
         <Version>955</Version>
     </Header>
     <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <inventorystatus>
             <itemid>281077289788</itemid>
             <quantity>500</quantity>
             <sku>MGA10003</sku>
             <startprice>6.90</startprice>
         </inventorystatus>
     </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>   
     <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <inventorystatus>
             <itemid>271171602595</itemid>
             <quantity>500</quantity>
             <sku>MGA10215</sku>
             <startprice>20.90</startprice>
         </inventorystatus>
     </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
     <ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <inventorystatus>
             <itemid>281449929626</itemid>
             <quantity>8</quantity>
             <sku>MGA12496.3</sku>
             <startprice>18.90</startprice>
         </inventorystatus>
     </ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
 </BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```